# Give advanced ownership

Tags: permissions, online

I am the owner of a SP with subfolders. For each subfolder, I want to make owner specific people within the company.

These should be able to modify and invite others to their own sub-folder, but should not be able to access the other subfolders.

Do you know what kind of permission should I give to each of them?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to create a SharePoint group per folder and give the permissions to that folder to the SharePoint group.

In the setting of the group, you set the person that you want as group owner and give him permissions to add or remove people from that group.

[image]